# Taxes on a stipend contract in Norway?

Tags: income-tax, norway

I just moved to Norway on a EU fellowship. The contract states that it is not a working contract, but a stipend contract. I know in other European Countries, you don't have to pay tax with this type of contract. Do I have to pay taxes in Norway on this income? If yes, how can I calculate the amount of tax I should pay?

Thank you very much

Comment: Check if your home country has tax treaty with Norway, it is likely to be discussed there.

Comment: Yes there actually is:
http://www.regjeringen.no/upload/kilde/fin/red/2001/0044/ddd/pdfv/127893-hellas_2.pdf
But I think you would have to be a lawyer to understand it 
:(

Comment: Article 20 covers you. You need to talk to a local tax adviser on how to actually claim the benefit (reporting might be required). In the US universities usually have an "international students" office that helps with such matters.

Comment: Thanx for the answer. The only gray area is if they can claim that I am not a "student"... However, one could consider a fellowship as "training" I guess